# Is it possible to toggle ngAnimate with a single button?

Tags: angularjs, toggle, ng-animate

Hi I am trying to use [this](http://augus.github.io/ngAnimate/) with ngAnimate but I am running into confusing as I try to make the animation toggle with one single button.

I need item A to trigger item `B` to slide in. If I click `A` again, `B` goes back to its original position. I want to do that without extra coding i.e. controller definition and such. I have been trying to execute this in the directive:

```
<a id="A" ng-click="B = !B" ng-class="{ active:B }">SLIDE!</a>

          <div  ng-show="B" input type="text" name="search-terms"  placeholder="Enter search terms..." class="animate slide-left"></div>
```

But nothing happens. Is the `ng-show` used in the right context here? Shouldn't it be `ng-class` (I tried but it did not work)? The examples I found work but use another button to toggle back to the original state. I need the same buttons to add and remove the classes. Shouldn't this be a standard feature?

EDITED:

I have [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/N8KBmhVIE5JtKq3YgTzZ?p=preview) example but as you can see it needs "2 buttons" in order to send the text back to its original state.

Comment: create a demo that replicates problem

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/N8KBmhVIE5JtKq3YgTzZ?p=preview (2 buttons)

Comment: is this what you want? http://plnkr.co/edit/0yZVHyJ7I3pmb0H8JkW9?p=preview

Comment: Bang on! Thanks for this. Would you be able to explain what this does" ng-class="{'css-class':searchBox}" or is it just basically targetting the searchBox class with css class?

Comment: no, searhcbox is a boolean

Comment: So what is the meaning of " css-class':searchBox" ?